# Does OpenSSL support the extension 'subject directory attributes'?

Tags: pyopenssl

I am using PyOpenSSL which is the thin wrapper of OpenSSL to add the extension 'subject directory attributes' to a certificate by a Python program. The extension names 'subjectDirAttrs' and 'subjectDirectoryAttributes' have been tried but the error occurs:

```
 "OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('X509 V3 routines', 'DO_EXT_NCONF', 'unknown extension name'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')]".
```

As PyOpenSSL is the wrapper of OpenSSL, can anyone make it clear that whether OpenSSL supports the extension 'subject directory attributes' and what is the proper name in programming if OpenSSL supports it?

The other question is the error is reported as follows when I add the extension 'certificate policies' to a certificate by PyOpenSSL.

```
"OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('X509 V3 routines', 'DO_EXT_NCONF', 'no config database'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')]"
```

What is the config database? Does it refer to /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf?  How to use it to add the extension 'certificate policies' to a certificate by PyOpenSSL?
   Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Does OpenSSL support the extension 'subject directory attributes'?

It kind of depends. OpenSSL can work with a certificate that has them, which means things won't fail with an "unsupported" error if they are present. The problem is, there's nothing available to parse them for user programs. You have to roll your own parsing logic.

Also see [How to parse Subject Directory Attributes Extension?](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-May/005811.html) on the OpenSSL users mailing list. The thread offers some suggestions for parsing them. Here's from the thread:

- *"Someone would have to write ASN1 parsing code.  There are examples all over the place within OpenSSL; see the various d2i_XXX and i2d_XXX functions.  There are macro/define’s available to make the job easier.  But, it is not really documented."*
- *"Looks like the type isn't X509_NAME_ENTRY but X509_ATTRIBUTE and the extension
  is a SEQUENCE OF Attribute. We don't have the direct equivalent as a specific
  type IIRC but it isn't hard to add one just follow what is done for
  GENERAL_NAMES which is a SEQUENCE OF GENERAL_NAME... You can either add a custom extension or just parse the structure from the
  extentsion contents."*